# Django - Is there a better way to send bulk Twilio text messages?

Tags: python, django, django-views, twilio, twilio-api

I'm currently using the following views.py function **sendsmss** to allow a user to do a bulk sms message to their list of subscribers, after the user has completed an html form with the sms they want to send to their subscribers:

```
def sendsmss(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subscribers = Subscriber.objects.all()

        sms = request.POST['sms']

        mytwilionum = "+13421234567"

        ACCOUNT_SID = TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
        AUTH_TOKEN = TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
        client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

        for subscriber in subscribers:
            subscriber_num = subscriber.phone_number
            client.messages.create(
                to= subscriber_num,
                from_=mytwilionum,
                body=sms
            )

        return redirect('homepage')
```

This function works, but I have only tested the bulk send with 3 subscribers. If there were 100s or 1000s of subscribers how long would this take .. if it takes long then would user be waiting for task to complete before redirect to homepage happens? Is there a better way to do this in Django?

Comment: You can use job queue using something like [django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions are very subjective and I will try to answer those accordingly:

> If there were 100s or 1000s of subscribers how long would this take

This is totally dependent on performance of Twilio. The API client is using the requests library and it is creating the messages one by one for each subscriber. In an ideal scenario the time taken seems proportional to the number of subscribers.

> if it takes long then would user be waiting for task to complete before redirect to homepage happens?

Based on your current implementation, Yes. The `return redirect('homepage')` will be executed only after the message has been sent to all the subscribers. In case, there is an error it will be thrown and the page won't redirect to the home page.

> Is there a better way to do this in Django?

Yes, there are. You can use an asynchronous job queue e.g. [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and hook it up with [django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). In this, you can start an async task in celery and return a response to the user immediately. You can also choose to display progress of the running celery task to the user (if required).

Comment: thank you. Once I have learned celery is it relatively easy to implement. Is it worth the time to implement for this single use case? I know my questions including this one are extremely subjective, but please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I think if you want the users to have a good user experience, it is work checking out.